# Bad gateways with large POST uploads and my apache + varnish + plone setup

Tags: apache, ssl, plone, varnish, proxypass

This is a rather complicated scenario, so I would highly appreciate any pointer to the correct direction.

So I have setup apache on server A to proxy https traffic το server B, that is a plone site behind varnish and apache.

I connect to A and can browse the site on https, everything is fine. However, problems start when I upload files, via plone's POST forms. I can upload small files (~1 MB), but when I try to upload a 50MB file, I wait all the time till the file is uploaded, and when the indication is 100%, I get a Bad gateway (The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.)

It seems to me that something timeouts between the communication of A and B and instead of being redirected to the correct url, I get a Bad gateway, not to mention that the file is not uploaded.

On the apache log I see

```
[error] proxy: pass request body failed
```

As suggested on other threads, I've experimented with the following values with no luck

```
force-proxy-request-1.0
proxy-nokeepalive
KeepAlive 
KeepAliveTimeout 
proxy-initial-not-pooled
Timeout 
ProxyTimeout
```

Sooooo..any suggestions? Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: You'll need to extend the timeout limit for the upstream server to respond.

Comment: may be plone is kicking the request out.. see anything in the plone error log?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Nothing weird on the plone side, as far as I can see. Regarding the timeout limits on the upstream apache server, what options could be helpful to add, that are low by default, for such a case?

Comment: Looks like the same basic issue as http://serverfault.com/questions/79741/php-apache-post-limit

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the varnish configuration? varnish has some timeouts of its own, I am familiar with send_timeout which usually breaks downloads if they fail to finish within a few seconds (Varnish really isn't any good for large downloads, because you end doing stupid things like configuring send_timeout=7200 to make it work).

Also, set first_byte_timeout to a larger number for that backend, because a large file upload might delay plone's response just enough to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `Timeout` and `KeepAliveTimeout` in the apache virtual host file worked for me.

Example:

```
Timeout 3600
KeepAliveTimeout 50
```